# Unable to Show/Display Custom Alert

Tags: ios, custom-controls, uialertview, modalviewcontroller

I found this cool looking "Custom Alert" iOS Control. But the problem is that, it is not working as it supposed to be.

Whenever I tried to show the Alert. It seems to place an **invisible** **overlay** on top of my current view and causes the underlying it not to respond to subsequent touchess.

Here is the cool control

[Flourish UI](https://github.com/unicorn/FlourishUI)

[image]

The example project itself is not working as it should.

So I tried to use the control myself in my app. But I couldnt get it to work even after following the straight forward guide from the GitHub page.

I am trying to use the **Modal** control which is suppose to open an alert, but It looks like it did not display the alert, but I think the alert is invisible after it is called because I couldnt do any other presses on the button.

Looks like there is something wrong in the show() function of the Modal class, but I couldnt figure it out. Everything just seemed sooo right.

https://github.com/unicorn/FlourishUI/blob/master/FlourishUI/FlourishUI/Modal.swift

Could anyone find the problem please?

This is just very confusing, spent the last 4 hours banging head against the wall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 6.3 caused some breaking changes with UIViewControllers initialization. The fix is to remove the vanilla `init()` method, turn the custom initializer into a convenience method `convenience init(title: String?, body: String?, status: Status)` and the code will work. Otherwise, just go ahead and pull down the new code, because I pushed the fix on github :)